# How to search data nested table data using Bootstarp datatables using Codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I have a table created using bootstrap datatables and when I search data it's working in the table .

but I have created a nested table on every rows. this nested table will show when I click 'show customers' link on particular row .

Now when I search elements from parent table it searches only parent table elements , I want to search child table elements as well as.

How to do this.

Html Code Of Table :

```
    <table class="table table-hover" id="table2">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
    <th>Action</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
      <tr>
                <td>1</td>
    <a href="#" onClick="project_list('<?=$item->bldr_ID;?>',0)">
                    details
                  </a>
                </td>
              </tr>


//Here generate another child table when I click details link (will call "project_list" function using ajax)

// Now want to search element both parent and child elements from parent table search column

    </tbody>
          </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Datatables can only search local things, which are in the table. You have two choices:

1. You write the «project_list» data in your table during creation and hide them.
2. You make a server side search https://datatables.net/manual/server-side.